# Best of the bests

Tags: grammar

I was wondering about this usage and how acceptable is the nominalization of the superlative "best" as in the phrase "best of the bests". At first I found only obviously very specific uses of "the bests" such as in this example from Google Books:

> ... five bests (best self, best team, best partner, best investment,
>   and best citizen) will improve financial performance, then the proof
>   is in the total shareholder return they generate. Otherwise, the bests
>   are only interesting concepts or nice things ..

and only noticed its use in contexts such as this idiomatic "best of the bests":

> Ashley's dream was to be a world-famous artist. So, she was heading
>   out in a few weeks to attend school and live in a small flat along the
>   Seine River and study under some of the best of the bests.

but then I discovered loads of "the bests of interests" examples like :

> From the stewardship point of view, a CEO in a dual role is working in
>   **the bests interests** of the shareholders and is intrinsically motivated
>   to operate in this capacity.
>
> the administrator should accept the prospective purchaser's
>   stipulation and proceed with the sale if he considers that to be in
>   **the bests interests** of creditors
>
> However, **the bests interests** of the child are ...

and in contexts of achieving certain result in athletics, especially with "personal", "personal bests":

> The 15-year-old registered personal bests of 1.62m (high jump), 8.91m
>   (shot put), 27.43s (200m) and 5.09m in the long jump over two days
>   of..

So how acceptable is this nominalization of "the best" to you?

Comment: What about 'the elite'? I'd say 'the best of the best' in any case.

Comment: I find all three examples of "the bests of interests" to be no more than typos.

Comment: It would usually be, "the best of the best". "Bests" is very strange and not used colloquially. It is defined in some places as the 3rd person present of best but I find it extremely odd sounding. This, "the *best* interests of the child...", sounds far more idiomatic.

Comment: And yes, agree with @marcellothearcane. "The best of the best" is an idiomatic phrase in English to mean, "the most elite".

Comment: From "Men in Black": "Caption America ova here _best of the best of the best_.... sir!..... with honors..

Comment: Thank you all for contributing your answers, it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the word best as a noun is perfectly acceptable.

**Best** is a singular noun and its plural does not technically exist. [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/best)

'Bests' is an incorrect way of spelling the word 'best'. Now, there are many who use and have commonly used the *incorrect* word 'bests'. However, there are various words that only have a singular form. Think of furniture, money, greed, etc... When using these words, you say "The furniture *is*", "Money *is*", "Greed *is*", etc...
You can mind more examples of such words [here](https://www.englishlci.edu/blog/english-grammar-lessons/did-you-know-that-these-words-have-no-plural/).

So in your examples, all the spellings 'bests' are all misspellings of the word 'best'. Apart from that, the nominalization of the verb 'best' is commonplace and accepted.

The phrase '*best interests*' is also just that, not '*best **of** interests*'.
Example:

> I have your best interests at heart. 
>   [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20someone%27s%20%28best%29%20interests%20at%20heart)

It is also:

> Best of the **best**.

If you want to talk of various best achievements, it is correct to say something such as:

> My best achievements in the following fields are: 1.62m (high jump), 8.91m (shot put), 27.43s (200m), ...
>   or
>   I have various best achievements which are ...

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps thank you Akaisteph :) Making plural of the superlative like "bests" would be a major proof of the nominal status of the word, but since this use has been firmly rejected by all of the contributors here, it rather supports analysis of the word as a "fused determiner-head" as it is named in The Cambridge Grammar. In this analysis "the best" is a modifier, and whatever noun it modifies is implied (considered as left out from the phrase). Anyway, as to the plural of words which are obviously adjectives, in this construction, one that comes to mind is "Reds" for Liverpool football club.

Comment: I think "bests" make sense in certain contexts. For example, if I'm competing in several different events tomorrow I might say that "I hope I beat my personal bests" meaning I want to beat my personal best time running, and, separately, my personal best time swimming, etc.